# I can't change base memory of kali linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I downloaded Virtual Box and Kali Linux to an external hard. I can't change base memory from virtual box settings. How can I change it ??

Comment: Look in VBOX settings. If you are talking about memory (ram) just change it.  If you are talking about disk space, see if you can change. You may need to rebuild your machine

Comment: You need to ensure the guest is not running. You need write permissions to the directory & its contents where you have stored the vm.